# How to use QMetaMethod with QObject::connect

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have two instances of QObject subclasses and two QMetaMethod instances of signal in one of objects and slot in another object. I want to connect this signal and slot with each other.

I've looked through the qobject.h file and find that SIGNAL() and SLOT() macro are just add "1" or "2" character to the beginning of method signature so it looks like it should be possible to add the same character to the beginning of string returned by QMetaMethod::signature() but this approach depends on some undocumented internals of toolkit and may be broken at any time by a new version of Qt.

Does anybody know reliable way to connect signals and slots through their QMetaMethod reflection representation?

**Edited:**
I've created suggestion in Qt issue tracker:
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-10637
If anybody also interested in this feature you can vote for this ticket there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is no way to make it work without relying on internal implementation. If I were you, I'd submit feature request to [Qt bug tracker](https://bugreports.qt.io/secure/Dashboard.jspa), write a code that mimics current behavior SIGNAL/SLOT macros and add unit test that will fail when SIGNAL/SLOT behavior changes.

There might be a simpler solution to the problem you're trying to solve: describe what exactly are you trying to do without any implementation details.

Comment: It looks like you are right. I'll try to ask in Qt-interest mailing list and if there will be no answer I'll fill a wishlist entry.

Comment: I have some generated proxy classes which creates and sends RPC request when you call slot in them and emits signals when receiving some RPC request over the network (it's my own small opensource library http://qremotesignal.googlecode.com). I want to add function which can automatically connect all RPC shared signals and slot in proxy class with signals and slots of some target class which do real work in an application using this library.

Answer (score 19):

This has been fixed as of Qt 4.8.0:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-10637

Suppose we have a QObject* m_subject, and wish to connect the change-notification signal of a property to a propertyChanged() slot:

```
const QMetaObject* meta = m_subject->metaObject();
QMetaProperty prop = meta->property(meta->indexOfProperty("myProperty"));
if (prop.hasNotifySignal()) {
    QMetaMethod signal = prop.notifySignal();
    QMetaMethod updateSlot = metaObject()->method(
        metaObject()->indexOfSlot("propertyChanged()"));
    connect(m_subject, signal, this, updateSlot);
}
```

I successfully used this to make a QWidget subclass which finds all the properties of any QObject and creates a QLineEdit for each of them, with a connection to keep the QLineEdit updated whenever the corresponding property changes.  (Because I didn't find a way to pass a  propertyID value to propertyChanged() though, it was necessary to make a subclass of QLineEdit and implement propertyChanged() there.  QSignalMapper didn't help, because all the properties are in the same object.)

Comment: Yes it was fixed by my own patch sent to Qt :)

Comment: thanks a lot. no simpler way to get metamethod ? Trying to implement MVC pattern in qt :) and this is very usefull.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to MBack, I now use metamethods to connect my view to my model's properties dynamically for MVVM or MVC pattern.
In order to respect DRY, a boilerplate is required with something like this :

```
 void MyClass::connectSignalToSlot(QObject* sender, std::string signalName, QObject* receiver, std::string slotName)
 {
    int sigIdx = sender->metaObject()->indexOfSignal(signalName.c_str());
    auto signal = sender->metaObject()->method(sigIdx);
    int slotIdx = receiver->metaObject()->indexOfSlot(slotName.c_str());
    auto slot = receiver->metaObject()->method(slotIdx);
    connect(sender,signal,receiver,slot);
 }

void MyClass::connectPropertyChangedToSlot(QObject* sender, std::string propName, QObject* receiver, std::string slotName)
{
   int sigIdx = sender->metaObject()->indexOfProperty(propName.c_str());
   auto signal = sender->metaObject()->property(sigIdx ).notifySignal();
   int slotIdx = receiver->metaObject()->indexOfSlot(slotName.c_str());
   auto slot = receiver->metaObject()->method(slotIdx);
   return connect(sender, signal, receiver, slot);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If signature method is public in QMetaMethod then the result shouldn't be broken by trolls and it's safe to use it (documentation says nothing about "dangers" when using QMetaMethod::signature method). I think you can safely use it. Just to be sure, what version of Qt you are using right now ?

Comment: not exactly correct. Since in QObject::connect documentation it's said that for signal and slot parameters SIGNAL() and SLOT() macro should be used I can't just use QMetaMethod::signature() function. Those macros output is differs from QMetaMethod::signature() output. The worst in this situation that those macros can't be used with strings calculated in runtime.

Comment: And I'm using Qt 4.6.2 (latest version available in Ubuntu 10.04 official repository)