# Introspection with QMetaProperty

Tags: c++, qt, qmetaobject

I have a class `ObjectA`

> ```
> class ObjectA : public QObject
> {
>     Q_OBJECT
>     Q_PROPERTY(int _a READ a WRITE setA NOTIFY aChanged)
> public:
>     ObjectA(int a) : _a(a) {}
>     int a() const { return _a;}
> public slots:
>     void setA(int a) { _a = a; emit aChanged(_a);}
> signals:
>     void aChanged(int);
> private:
>     int _a;
> };
> ```

and the class `ObjectB`

> ```
> class ObjectB : public QObject
> {
>     Q_OBJECT
>     Q_PROPERTY(int _b READ b WRITE setB NOTIFY bChanged)
> public:
>     ObjectB(int b) : _b(b) {}
>     int b() const { return _b;}
> public slots:
>     void setB(int b) { _b = b; emit bChanged(_b);}
> signals:
>     void bChanged(int);
> private:
>     int _b;
> };
> ```

And I would like do a signal/slot connection like this

> ```
> QObject::connect(&objA, SIGNAL(aChanged(int)), &objB, SLOT(setB(int)));
> ```

knowing only name's properties.

> ```
> ObjectA objA(10);
> ObjectB objB(5);
> ```

```
QObject * objectA = &objA;
const QMetaObject* metaObjectA = objectA->metaObject();
QMetaProperty metaPropertyA = metaObjectA->property(metaObjectA->indexOfProperty("_a"));


QObject * object = &objB;
const QMetaObject* metaObjectB = object->metaObject();
QMetaProperty metaPropertyB = metaObjectB->property(metaObjectB->indexOfProperty("_b"));

QObject::connect(&objA, metaPropertyA.notifySignal().methodSignature(), &objB, ... );

objA.setA(2);
std::cout << "objA.a() = " << objA.a() << " objB.b() = " << objB.b() << std::endl;
```

but the

> metaPropertyA.notifySignal().methodSignature()

doesn't return the function's pointer and I don't how get the set method pointer.

Comment: There's no documented way to get the method pointer. You don't need the method pointer to invoke the method, so I don't quite see the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: With @j123b567 I do the connect with : QMetaObject::connect(&objA, metaPropertyA.notifySignalIndex(), &objB, metaObjectB->indexOfMethod("setB1(int)")); Now I would like use the reflexion on my Q_PROPERTY to get the index of the write method (slot) and replace "metaObjectB->indexOfMethod("setB1(int)")"

Comment: There's a `QObject::connect` method that takes `QMetaMethod` arguments. You need to use that one. No need to use the indexes at all. You also need to tell us whether this is Qt 4 or Qt 5, since they differ a bit.

Comment: I know `QOBJECT::connect`. I don't know the implementation of ObjectA and ObjectB. I know only they are QObject and they have some Q_PROPERTY(TYPE _foo READ foo WRITE setFoo NOTIFY fooChanged). And I must connect two property of Object (whose I don't know the real type) knowing only the property's name. I use Qt5.3.

Answer (score 1):

`metaPropertyA.notifySignal().signature()` does not return method pointer but its signature (text representation) - in your case "aChanged(int)" and this is what you need for connect().

If you rather want to call this directly, you can use `metaPropertyA.notifySignal().invoke(...)`.

EDIT:
you need to connect some number and method name as SIGNAL and SLOT macro do

so you need to programaticcaly create

```
QObject::connect(&objA, "2aChanged(int)", &objB, "1setB(int)");
```

but how to get "1setB(int)" is another task

EDIT2:
I don't know what the number mean, because it is not index

Comment: Ok I see, but with ` QObject::connect(&objA, metaPropertyA.notifySignal().methodSignature(), &objB, SLOT(setB(int)));` I get "QObject::connect: Attempt to bind non-signal ObjectA::Changed(int)"

Comment: OK, I see you need to get something like this     QObject::connect(&objA, "2aChanged(int)", &objB, "1setB(int)");

Comment: SIGNAL(metaPropertyA.notifySignal().methodSignature()) doesn't compile so I must manually append "2"?

Comment: I think the number 1 and 2 are QMetaMethod::MethodType, but, with this enum, QMetaMethod::Signal = 1 and QMetaMethod::Slot = 2. So the number are inverted.

Comment: qDebug() << SIGNAL(aChanged(int)); writes "2aChanged(int)" but it is something that do MOC compiler. You can't use SIGNAL in other situation so I thing that you should add "2" manualy

Comment: Here is similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799412/how-to-use-qmetamethod-with-qobjectconnect

Comment: I found a solution to avoid append manually "2". QMetaObject::connect(&objA, metaPropertyA.notifySignalIndex(), &objB, metaObjectB->indexOfMethod("setB1(int)")); Now the problem is how get the index of a write method's property.

Comment: Is it possible to use lambda function and call `objB->setProperty("_b", value);` directly?

Comment: It is not necesery that property write function is a SLOT so it is the reason why there is no souch way to handle it as SLOT. You can use some naming trick like QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName do.