# cannot connect QMetaMethod with lambda

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qmetaobject

I have a base class Binded settings to bind property in it with given widgets, like LineEdit in example. I stuck with connecting signals and slot. As i see it's the same as provided code in answer on [How to use QMetaMethod with QObject::connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799412/how-to-use-qmetamethod-with-qobjectconnect)
                                       ^

```
class BindedSettings: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
bool bindWtToProp(QLineEdit* targetWt, const char* propertyName);
bool stringFromVariant(const QVariant& val, QString& result){...}
}
```

in cpp:

```
bool BindedSettings::bindWtToProp(QLineEdit *targetWt, const char *propertyName)
{
    QLineEdit* le = targetWt;
    QMetaProperty mp = metaObject()->property(metaObject()->indexOfProperty(propertyName));

    //connecting property notifiedSignal with reader lambda
    QMetaMethod signal = mp.notifySignal();
    connect(this, signal, this, [=](){
    }); //reader
    return true;
}
```

I have some classic connections(without qmetamethod) in the same function, but here what i get is

> C:\Projects\some\settings.cpp:279: error: no
>   matching function for call to
>   'BindedSettings::connect(BindedSettings*, QMetaMethod&,
>   BindedSettings*, BindedSettings::bindWtToProp(QLineEdit*, const
>   char*)::)'
>        connect(this, signal, this, ={});

Comment: This code can't be right, the *//reader* comment is breaking your lambda definition. Is this real code or just a copy/paste artifact?

Comment: I added it right here to show that I simplified it. Fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing 2 definitions of `QObject::connect()`:

1. `QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject *sender, const QMetaMethod &signal, const QObject *receiver, const QMetaMethod &method, Qt::ConnectionType type = Qt::AutoConnection)`
2. `QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject *sender, PointerToMemberFunction signal, const QObject *context, Functor functor, Qt::ConnectionType type = Qt::AutoConnection)`

But `connect()` has no overload that takes both a `QMetaMethod` and a `Functor`.

This exact same question has already been asked 5 years ago on [Qt forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/38143/qobject-connect-qmetamethod-signal-to-functor/2), the answer was:

> Connections to functors/lambdas use function pointers. They need to be resolved at 
>   compile-time, because the compiler needs to know what types of
>   function pointers you are using. You can't use runtime strings.

I believe the situation has not changed.